# Im stuck with a template class in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, arraylist

so ive been tryind to create a simple array list class and got stuck allready in the beginning...

my header file ( i deleted my .cpp file and still got the same message )

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H
#define ARRAYLIST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class ArrayList {
private:
    T *arr;
    int length;

public:
    ArrayList();

    void Insert(T item);

    void Print();

    //friend &ostream operator<< (ostream &out, ArrayList &al);
};

#endif
```

and my error

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ArrayList<int>::ArrayList<int>(void)" (??0?$ArrayList@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Gannash\Desktop\Programming\C++WS\XMLReader\Debug\XMLReader.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Well, you've declared three member functions, where are the definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like you only declared methods of the class and not defined them

**Put all the definitions in the header**

Comment: i actualy did declare the constructor in the .cpp file but i didnt post it here... still same error message

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining a template class you should provide all member functions implmeentations inline. The missing ctor is definitely a problem recognized, but other problems will show up when you actually use your class. In addition, there are standard containers that provide what you might want to achieve, most notably std::vector.

In addition using namespace in a header file is verboten (or at least greatly discouraged.) 
you should use std:: qualification instead, especially you only need it once.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined ArrayList(), Insert(), and Print() in a .cpp file.
You need either need to write code for those functions or turn them into pure virtual functions, aka `virtual Print()=0;`

Answer (score 0):

Let us dissect the error message:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ArrayList<int>::ArrayList<int>(void)" (??0?$ArrayList@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

`unresolved external symbol` => There is some symbol (here function) declared, but not defined

`ArrayList<int>::ArrayList<int>(void)` => Constructor or ArrayList class template instantiated with T = int

`referenced in function _main` => Probably there is code like following in main():

```
  ArrayList<int> IntList;
```

The solution is to provide an implementation of the constructor, perhaps as:

```
ArrayList() : arr( 0 ), length( 0 ) {}
```

inside the class body.

---

BTW, please feel free to see the following for your reference:

```
  std::array

  std::vector
```